# How can I throw an authentification error in a ATOM/OPDS feed?

Tags: xml, http-authentication, atom-feed

I am managing a e-book merchant site and providing an OPDS catalog so my customers can download their books directly via their e-book application or device (such as Marvin on iOS).

Of course this feed is only accessible via http-auth because I don't want anyone to be able to download ebooks, only legit customers, using their account's user and password.

When user and/or password are wrong, I would like to throw an error message or error code that an OPDS catalog reader would understand. I'm currently using a `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized` header but is there a way do this with the ATOM and/or OPDS standard ?

Comment: It is explained in section "13. Securing OPDS Catalogs" http://opds-spec.org/specs/opds-catalog-1-1-20110627/